# Rotate camera in three.js using mouseover

Tags: javascript, three.js, 3d, camera

I want to rotate my camera to look at the object from all directions using a mouseover. How can it be done using three js.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest looking at [Orbit Controls](https://threejs.org/docs/#examples/en/controls/OrbitControls) in the official documentation.

Comment: I need to use [pointerlock control](https://threejs.org/examples/?q=control#misc_controls_pointerlock) but it shows an error while implementing